# Trouble with SharedPreferences between classes, from inside handler

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My goal is to get the restpost variable into the second class, so it can be sent via httppost. 
There is a SharedPreferences object already in use which is for user settings. I have googled this at least 100 times, and checked every relevant post here.

The main activity contains this:

```
        private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BTService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to,mConnectedDeviceName));
                mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                break;
    ... //then...eventually this..

                        Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("restpost", restpost);
                editor.commit();
            HttpService sendNow = new HttpService();
            sendNow.sendData();
```

The second class is below.

```
    public class HttpService extends PreferenceActivity{


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public void sendData(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String host = sharedPrefs.getString("host_text", "NULL");
    String muser = sharedPrefs.getString("user_text", "NULL");
    String mpw = sharedPrefs.getString("pw_text", "NULL");
    String maxurl = sharedPrefs.getString("restpost", "NULL");

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(maxurl);
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }
    }
```

The ultimate goal is to do an http event during an active BT connection. This is based on the BluetoothChat example, if that helps. 
I also have a handler & timed task running to execute BT messages repeatedly - no more than 1 per minute.

Here's the error:

11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:160)
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:366)
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at com.clicsys.motomon.HttpService.sendData(HttpService.java:29)
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at com.clicsys.motomon.MainActivity$3.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:467)
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
11-21 09:08:30.395: E/AndroidRuntime(5012):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpService sendNow = new HttpService();

// ...

public class HttpService extends PreferenceActivity
```

You cannot instantiate activities with `new` (well you *can* but they are not properly initialized). Instantiate activities via `Intent` and use it as a `Context` in `onCreate()` or later in the lifecycle.

In your case it seems `HttpService` should not be an activity at all. Pass in a valid `Context` object as a parameter to `sendData()` and use it instead of `this`.

Comment: Thanks. Can I call the method in the 2nd activity instead? That's really all I need. I just need to do the Http Post, and I can't from anywhere inside the main activity - note my ultimate goal...

Comment: I crafted it into an inner class extending AsyncTask. No preferences needed - works great. Thanks for putting me back on track...